# How can i access all variable values in json list

Tags: c#, json, list

I want to access variables values from json list in `C#`.
 my `json` String is as below

plase suggest me the way to access variable from json list .

example :-

```js
 {
                  "BillTransList": [
                    {
                      "aa": "13",
                      "ss": "200",
                      "LessItemList": [
                        {
                          "a": "13",
                          "b": "19"
                        },
                        {
                          "a": "17",
                          "b": "18"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "aa": "13",
                      "ss": "200",
                      "LessItemList": [
                        {
                          "a": "3",
                          "b": "9"
                        },
                        {
                          "a": "7",
                          "b": "8"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ],
                  "aq": "2"
                }
```

suggestions and corrections are welcome

thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your Question does not meet our requirements. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking on how to ask good questions

Answer (score 2):

You can create class to deserialize your JSON.

```
public class LessItemList
{
    public string a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
}

public class BillTransList
{
    public string aa { get; set; }
    public string ss { get; set; }
    public List<LessItemList> LessItemList { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<BillTransList> BillTransList { get; set; }
    public string aq { get; set; }
}
```

than you can deserialize using the below code

```
var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
```

than you can access LessItemList simply by using LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

***Aliasgar Rajpiplawala***'s answer is Nice.

And I will do some supplement:

You should use some library to deserialize JSON string, such like **Json.NET** ([Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)).

And you can create your class using **Json2Csharp** (http://json2csharp.com/). Paste your json into it, and your class will be generated automic.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Aliasgar Rajpiplawala & Chris Shao i did it with Jtoken.Parse(obj). your answer was valuable to me and  help me a lot